# Algorithm design (with constraints) to reduce bipartite graph to a tree/forest

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I had a question regarding designing an algorithm to make a bipartite graph acyclic. I hope someone could help me out here. The problem statement is described below:

Consider an undirected bipartite graph G = (U,V,E), where U = {u_1, u_2, ...u_M} is a set of M nodes, V = {v_1, v_2, ..., v_N} is a set of N nodes, and E is the set of edges connecting nodes in U to nodes in V. For simplicity, assume that the graph is connected and cyclic, i.e., has cycles.

The aim is to design an algorithm that eliminate cycles and reduces the graph to a tree or forest as follows. The algorithm proceeds in rounds. A round is described as choosing each node u_i, i = 1, 2, ..., M, in U and removing an edge connected to it. In case a node u_i is isolated (i.e., it has no edges connected to it) we ignore it and proceed. This way at most M edges are removed in each round. The algorithm stops when the graph reduces to a tree or forest at the end of some round.

I wish to know if it is possible to have a polynomial-time algorithm (in M, N) for designing the rounds such that the number of rounds is minimized (for reducing the graph to a tree/forest).

Comment: What do you mean by 'designing a round' ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum He's asking how to choose the edge to remove in each round such that the total number of rounds is minimal.

Comment: @ChrisPitman _round is described as choosing each node..._ , so knowing the problem you think what he meant to say is "round is describe as choosing **a** node..."

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sorry, I was unclear. I interpret the above as meaning that every node in U is iterated through in each round, and an edge is removed from each. So it is not minimizing the number of total edge removals, it is minimizing the number of rounds where the number of edges removed is <= R*M (ie, probably lots of extra edges, if considering the case where a single removal would have created a tree).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, by 'designing a round' you mean choosing which edges to remove from each node?

Comment: Yes, by 'designing a round' I meant choosing which edge to remove from each node. To be precise, a round comprises removing an edge from each node in U (one edge per node) whose degree is non-zero. Maybe the word 'round' was misleading, it could be replaced by 'stage'.

Comment: My approach to the problem was to consider the BFS tree of the bipartite graph. Assuming nodes in U are colored black and nodes in V are colored white, then the levels of the BFS tree will be alternately colored. The presence of cross edges in the BFS tree will indicate presence of cycles and their removal would make the graph acyclic. I believe that the solution would involve finding the BFS tree configuration that minimizes the max number of cross edges connected to nodes colored black; I think this min-max quantity would be the optimal number of rounds for reducing the graph to tree/forest.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, it comes up as a sub-problem in a research problem I am working on related to index coding.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Cycle article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29#Cycle_detection).

To detect a cycle in any undirected graph, perform a DFS, maintaining a list of visited nodes. If you detect a back edge, it is part of a cycle and you can remove that edge from the graph. A DFS with no back edges has no cycles. Complexity is O(M+N).